# Terraform GCE metadata with variables

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-compute-engine, terraform

I'm trying to pass a certificate as a metadata to my project, so every newly created instance would have an access to it. I'm trying to achieve it via terraform resource "google_compute_project_metadata".
I'm trying to pass this:

```
resource "google_compute_project_metadata" "cert" {
  metadata {
    ${var.cluster_prefix}crt-etcd="${var.cert_path}/cert.pem"
    ${var.cluster_prefix}key-etcd="${var.cert_path}/cert-key.pem"
  }
  depends_on = ["null_resource.generate_cert"]
}
```

But it fails with

```
Error loading modules: module cert: Error parsing .terraform/modules/b47b15a6431fda040235ee9e28b0836d/cert.tf: At 14:5: illegal char
```

As I understand, it doesn't like using a variable as a key. 
But should I omit it, it would me a mess in project's metadata. Any workarounds? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic keys are not supported when using the block syntax like this, but since `metadata` is a map attribute (as opposed to a structured child block) you can assign it using an expression that constructs a dynamic map, like this:

```
resource "google_compute_project_metadata" "cert" {
  metadata = "${map("${var.cluster_prefix}crt-etcd", "${var.cert_path}/cert.pem", "${var.cluster_prefix}key-etcd", "${var.cert_path}/cert-key.pem")}"
  depends_on = ["null_resource.generate_cert"]
}
```

For more information on how this works, refer to [the docs for the `map` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#map-key-value-).

Comment: Great! Thanks! It seems to work, but is there a way of passing contents of file as a value for metadata? metadata = "${map("${var.cluster_prefix}crt-etcd", "${file(var.cert_path)/cert.pem")}" Fails as an incorrect.

Comment: Oh! Managed to do it! Rather scary expression =) metadata = "${map("${var.cluster_prefix}crt-etcd", "${file("${var.cert_path}/certs/cert.pem")}", "${var.cluster_prefix}key-etcd", "${file("${var.cert_path}/certs/cert-key.pem")}")}" Thanks a lot!